# Show that for two orthogonal bases $V_1, V_2$ of the same subspacce $M$ of $C^n$, we have $V_1 V_1^T x = V_2 V_2^T x $

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that for two orthonormal bases $V_1, V_2$ of the same subspacce $M$ of $C^n$, we have $V_1 V_1^T x = V_2 V_2^T x, \forall x$.

This is what I have done so far:

$V_1V_1^Tx=V_2V_2^Tx \rightarrow V_1^TV_1V_1^Tx = V_2^Tx \rightarrow V_1^TV_1V_1^TV_1x = V_2^TV_1x \rightarrow V_1^TV_1V_1^TV_1 = I$ so $V_1^TV_1$ should be $I$. But I dont think thats true. This is somehow a homework, and I would like to find the solution by myself. So some hints before the final solution would be appreciated.

Comment: $V_1^TV_1$ does not have to be $I$, it can also be zero for some $x$. And it seems like you are going the wrong way, as you have to prove $V_1V_1^Tx = V_2V_2^Tx$, so it cannot imply anything, it has to be implied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=m+o$, where $m \in M$ and $o \in M^\bot$. Then $m = V_1 y_1$ for some $y_1$ and hence we have $V_1^T x = V_1^T m = V_1^T V_1 y_1 = y_1$.

Then
$V_1 V_1^T x = V_1 y_1 = m$.

Comment: I did not quite understand your approach, would you please explain more

Comment: The approach is to show that $V_k V_k^T$ is the orthogonal projection onto $M$ for $k=1,2$. Every $x \in \mathbb{C}^n$ can be decomposed uniquely as $x=m+o$ where $m \in M$ and $o \bot m$.